# not able to fetch data from form in php

Tags: php

```
Not able to fetch $fnamef and $lnamel from form!!!
```

PLease help
here is my code:
i take values from form in an array as team of members and want to store it in database

```
    $fname=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $lname=$_REQUEST['last'];
    $cnct=$_REQUEST['ph'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $sem=$_REQUEST['semester'];
    $dept=$_REQUEST['dept'];
    $event=$_REQUEST['event'];
    $tno=$_REQUEST['tno'];
    $tname=$_REQUEST['namet'];
    $fnamef=array();
    $lnamel=array();
    for($m=0;$m<$tno;$m++)
    {
        $fnamef[$m]=$_REQUEST['f'.($m+1)];
        $lnamel[$m]=$_REQUEST['l'.($m+1)];
    }
    for($m=0;$m<$tno;$m++)
    {
        echo $fnamef[$m];
        echo $lnamel[$m];
    }

    echo $tname;
    echo $tno;
    echo $fname;
    echo $lname;
?>
```

Comment: How can we possibly help you without knowing how your form looks like?

Comment: please show your HTML form.

Comment: and what is your expected result?

Comment: or do you want to print like:    f1
l1
f2
l2
f3
l3
f4
l4
f5
l5
f6
l6
f7
l7
f8
l8
f9
l9
f10
l10
test
10
test
test

Comment: yes i wanna print like that

Comment: Form:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byg9A0FoxXRWekhkTHRVUTV1b2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @HarshilKothari: ihave sent u a piece of code chk...

Comment: okay thanks... @devpro

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is it so i can't able to explain it, but as per **your comments** here is the solution and mentioned what i have changed in this code:

```
$fname=$_REQUEST['name'];
$lname=$_REQUEST['last'];
$cnct=$_REQUEST['ph'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$sem=$_REQUEST['semester'];
$dept=$_REQUEST['dept'];
$event=$_REQUEST['event'];
$tno=$_REQUEST['tno'];
$tname=$_REQUEST['namet'];

$fnamef=array();
$lnamel=array();


for($m=0;$m<$tno;$m++)
{
    $fnamef[$m] = 'f'.($m+1); // only change this part
    $lnamel[$m] = 'l'.($m+1); // only change this part
}
for($m=0;$m<$tno;$m++)
{
    echo $fnamef[$m] . "<br>";
    echo $lnamel[$m] . "<br>";
}

echo $tname . "<br>";
echo $tno . "<br>";
echo $fname . "<br>";
echo $lname . "<br>";
```

Comment: i didnt get the mail